# Ruby on rails bytes checksum

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arrays

I have this bytes "\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x23" packet 
I need to send it with it's checksum,
I have also the packet with the checksum "\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x23\xDA",
but I don't know how to calculate the checksum for this packet or other packets, any help!
Thanks

Comment: There are lots of types of "Checksum". Could you provide a little more context? Are you trying to match an existing algorithm? If so, please give some sample inputs and outputs, and explain what you do already understand or have tried. You may have some luck with http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html

Comment: Hi Neil,
Thanks for your replay,all I need to do is to sum this bytes as bytes (ORing) not as integers to get the sum of the packet, in the question this is the packet "\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x23" and the checksum is 0xDA I don't know how to get it using code

Comment: this is another packet "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x21\x04\x61\x64\x6D\x69\x6E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x61\x64\x6D\x69\x6E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
and this is the packet with the checksum "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x21\x04\x61\x64\x6D\x69\x6E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x61\x64\x6D\x69\x6E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should describe your problem more clearly if you want to get quick response here. Even after Neil asked you about the checksum, you didn't describe clearly how your checksum algorithm worked.

It **SEEMS** the way to get your checksum is

1. Break the packet into bytes

   `"\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x23"` => `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 35]`
2. Compute the sum of all bytes => `38`, i.e. `0x26`
3. Negate the sum as a signed byte => `0xDA`

Here may be a solution:

```
packet = "\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x23"
bytes = packet.bytes
sum = bytes.reduce(:+)
checksum = [ -sum ].pack('c')
packet_with_checksum = packet + checksum
```

You may need `packet.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')` (or on `checksum`) if you get an encoding error at the concatenation step.

Comment: thanks Arie, and sorry for the description